# Linker --whole-archive option

Tags: c, linux, linker, arm, embedded-linux

I am using `C` language.

I am linking static libraries with `--whole-archive`. Linker is `arm-none-eabi-ld`

For example, giving the following option to the linker:

```
--whole-archive abc.a def.a
```

But still I get linking error:

```
(.text.boot+0x94): undefined reference to `xyz'
...
```

Why is the linking error happening?

EDIT:

Full command with output:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Project1/kern'
arm-none-eabi-ld -o /home/Project1/kernel.elf -T memmap.ld  \
     hal/arm/arm_startup.o --whole-archive kunit.a hal.a fs.a --no-whole-archive /home/Project1/lib/lpc.a
hal/arm/arm_startup.o: In function `start':
(.text.boot+0x94): undefined reference to `mmu_init'
hal/arm/arm_startup.o: In function `halt':
(.text.boot+0x98): undefined reference to `exec_array'
hal.a(arm_int_handlers.o): In function `interrupt_svc':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `mmu_pagetable'
hal.a(arm_int_handlers.o): In function `interrupt_svc':
(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `_enter_kernel'
...
```

Out put of:

`readelf -Ws  kunit.a hal.a fs.a  | egrep ' (mmu_init|exec_array|mmu_pagetable|_enter_kernel)'`

is:

```
     9: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND mmu_pagetable
    10: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _enter_kernel
    12: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND mmu_pagetable
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to say what the issue is with the limited info you have given. At a minimum give the full build command that results in the link error. Any output that you used to reach your conclusions would also be helpful.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message? Are you sure it's `xyz` and not `xyz()` ?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Post updated. I believe `xyz` is `xyz()`

Comment: @kaylum Post updated

Comment: Can you add output from `readelf -Ws  kunit.a hal.a fs.a  | egrep ' (mmu_init|exec_array|mmu_pagetable|_enter_kernel)'` (all on single line).

Comment: @EmployedRussian Please check the output of your command in the edited post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the linking error happening?

Because the symbols that you are missing: `mmu_init`, `mmu_pagetable`, etc. are *in fact* not defined in the libraries you expected them to be defined in.

That's what `UND` in `readelf` output means.

Now, in order to tell you *why* these symbols are not defined, we'd need to know the origin of the libraries you expected them to be defined in, how these libraries were built, and possibly a lot of other details. Please ask a separate question with *all* the details that you can think of.

Comment: There is `UND` against `mmu_pagetable` but not against `mmu_init`. Does that mean both `mmu_pagetable` and `mmu_init` are not defined? Can you please explain in detail what the FULL `readelf` command is doing and also the different columns in the output. Request you to please put this in your answer please.

Comment: `mmu_init` is referenced from `hal/arm/arm_startup.o` so it will be undefined there.  `Can you please explain in detail`  Readelf [has it's own documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/readelf.html) there is no point in duplicating it here. `also the different columns` Some if it is documented in [objdump documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html). Generally research the ELF file type.